# Is it possible to grant a sandboxed app access to a file sent from an AppleScript?

Tags: macos, scripting, applescript, appstore-sandbox

I'm adding AppleScript support to my sandboxed Mac App Store app. I would like the user to be able to add files to the app through a script, using a command I wrote, like so:

```AppleScript
add file at path "/path/to/some/file/on.disk"
```

I specified the parameter of the command as type `file`, so it comes through to my app as an `NSURL`, and I can see the file URL's path (`po url.path`) in the debugger.

This is the definition of the command in the `sdef` file:

```XML
<!-- Contained by a suite -->
<command name="add file at path" code="ABCDABCD">
    <direct-parameter description="A file to add to the app" type="file" />
</command>
```

When I attempt to create a security-scoped bookmark to this file, I get an error:

> Could not open() the item

I need to be able to read the file on subsequent launches of the app, which is why I create a bookmark. This bookmark-creation code:

```objc
NSData *fileBookmark = [url bookmarkDataWithOptions:NSURLBookmarkCreationWithSecurityScope
                     includingResourceValuesForKeys:nil
                                      relativeToURL:nil
                                              error:&error];
```

I tried surrounding the code with `[url start(stop)AccessingSecurityScopedResource]`, which didn't make a difference.

**Update**

I've also determined that the app is unable to read the contents of the file, or to copy it into the app's container. The scripted app has *no* access to the file, aside from its path.

**Update 2**

I also tried placing the script in the `~/Application Scripts/bundleid` (`NSApplicationScriptsDirectory`) directory, and running it from an `NSUserScriptTask` inside my Cocoa code, and that yielded the same results (the file at the URL is still not readable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it turns out the problem had nothing to do with my app, but rather with the AppleScript I was using to call it. You need to send a file handle or alias, like the following:

```AppleScript
add file at path posix file "/path/to/some/file/on.disk"
add file at path "path:to:some:file:on.disk" as alias
```

When you just give a path (POSIX or otherwise), it still comes through as an `NSURL`, hence my confusion, but without punching a hole in the sandbox.

This behavior is not obvious, and difficult to troubleshoot, so I [filed a Radar](http://openradar.appspot.com/19680027).